# how to create an agentset with more than 8 neighbors in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

Netlogo has a primitive "neighbors" that can select 8 neighbors surrounding directly to the target at one time. But what if I wanna create an agentset from multiple layer surroundings, like primitive "in-radius" but in rectangular way, what kind of primitives should I use or how to arrange the codes in Netlogo?

Answer (score 1):

The following code is taken from the Models Library, Code Examples section, Moore & Von Neumann Example. If you want a rectangle rather than a square, you would still take the same approach of selecting particular `pxcor` and `pycor` values

```
to-report moore-offsets [n include-center?]
  let result [list pxcor pycor] of patches with [abs pxcor <= n and abs pycor <= n]
  ifelse include-center?
    [ report result ]
    [ report remove [0 0] result ]
end
```